# Kolmogorov's paper defining Bayesian sufficiency

Tags: bayesian, references, sufficient-statistics

I'm looking for a translation to either English, French or German of Kolmogorov's Russian paper

*[Kolmogorov, A. (1942). Sur l’estimation statistique des paramètres de la loi de Gauss. Bull. Acad. Sci. URSS Ser. Math. 6, 3–32.](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=im&paperid=3752&option_lang=eng)*

This seminal, oft-cited paper (e.g. in Lehmann and Romano's Testing Statistical Hypotheses (2008) p. 20 and in Blackwell and Ramamoorthi's A Bayes But Not Classically Sufficient Statistic (1982) p. 1) originated the concept of Bayesian Sufficiency.

Translations to other Romance languages or to Dutch are also welcome.

Comment: Did you learn Russian? ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: Nyet.

Comment: =D Well, you still have time. See you in 5. ;)